# Protect admin page with json web token

Tags: node.js, jwt

In my node backend, I have an endpoint that server render an admin page. 
The authentication is done with json web token so I want to protect the access to this page ('/admin') with jwt and ensure that only admin can access this page.

The problem is that I cannot transmit the jwt in the authorization header when I get this page (for example if I type `www.mydomain.com/admin` in the url bar).

So I'm asking how could I protect the access to this page ?

Note : I use `passport` with local strategy and `express-jwt`

Here's the code for the endpoint :

```
// routes
// login is handled by auth subapp.
router.get('/', jwt, jwtAdmin, (req, res) => {
  Game.findAll({order: [['g_name', 'ASC']]}).then(games => {
    if (!games) {
      res.status(404).send({error: "No games..."});
      return;
    }
    res.status(200).render('sections/admin',
    Object.assign(viewOptions, {
      games
    }));
  }).catch(error => res.status(500).json({error}));
});
```

jwt middleware :

```
const jwt = require('express-jwt');
const blacklist = require('express-jwt-blacklist');

module.exports = jwt({secret: process.env.SECRET, isRevoked: blacklist.isRevoked});
```

jwtAdmin middleware :

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.user) {
    res.status(401).send('you should login !');
    return;
  }

  if (!req.user.admin) {
    res.status(401).send('admin only !');
    return;
  }
  next();
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to pass the token through cookies.

[express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) has a special method (getToken) to create custom logic to decode a jwt. By implementing this, you can say that if there is no jwt in authorization header, decode it from cookies.

```
module.exports = jwt({
  secret: JWT_SECRET,
  getToken: function readFromBearerOrCookies(req) {
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
      return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    } else if (req.cookies && req.cookies.jwt) {
      return req.cookies.jwt;
    }
    console.log('No token received...');
    return null;
  }
});
```